# change the width on a specific page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css-float, image-resizing, autoresize

I think i have a easy issue for all people here. For me not so easy;)

I only would like to change the width on a specific page in Wordpress. I'm using the theme Touchfolio http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/about.html

This is the page I would like to change the width of http://karimphoto.com/about/ I like to change it from 900px to 700px wide, both the image and the text. I did start to create a new PHP template file but really don't know what I need to do.

I'm sure it's a no brainer if you know that you are doing but my knowledge in this is pretty bad.

Edit:

It works great with the code:

.page-id-247 .hentry, .page-id-247 .aligncenter {
    max-width: 700px !important;

The only problem I can see now is that the image won't resize any longer.

Any input on this?

Thanks,

Comment: since you have the page id the body class, you could just quick'n'dirty apply a css rule to that pages content `.page-id-247 #main {width: 700px; }`

Answer (score 2):

WordPress adds classes to the `body` tag containing the ID of the page which you can use to target specific pages in CSS. The ID of your about page is 247 so you can use the following to change the width as you asked. Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.page-id-247 .hentry, .page-id-247 .aligncenter {
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

The `.aligncenter` class targets the class used on your large image. It is set to 900px normally, so setting it to the same width as `.hentry` (the class used as on the page content container) will make your image the same width as your content.

Comment: WOW. You are fast :) Thanks, it was just what I was looking for. "The .aligncenter class targets the class used on your large image. It is set to 900px normally, so setting it to the same width as .hentry (the class used as on the page content container) will make your image the same width as your content." Sorry but you lost me a bit here. And if i like to change the horizontal position? Many thanks

Comment: I can't gett the image to be responsive and resize like the text. 
 
Now I'm using this code: .page-id-247 .hentry, .page-id-247 .aligncenter { max-width: 700px !important;
 
What did I miss?

Any input on this?

Comment: Did you work this out? Image looks to be working well responsively

Comment: Yes think it's working fine now. Just added this:

    .page-id-247 img.aligncenter {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

Answer (score 0):

1. The body tag has a class specifying the current page ID, so you could do something like this.

Paste this into the Custom CSS field in your theme options panel:

```
Code:
.page-id-111 .container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Change the page ID and the maximum desired width to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This code will fix the responsive issue I had:

.page-id-247 img.aligncenter { height: 100%; width: 100%; }